# vector plot of electric field in closed surface

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to put the vector plot inside of the closed rectangle box. 
Please, help me with how I can combine them.

```
show[VectorPlot3D[{(3 + 2*x^2), 0, 0}, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 0.7}, 
{z,0, 0.7}], 
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Cuboid[{0.4, 0, 0}, {1, 0.4, 0.4}]}, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Lighting -> {LightBlue}]]
```

Comment: Replace `show` by `Show`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the suggestions from  @HenrikSchuhmacher 's comment  together with `RegionFunction`

```
Show[{VectorPlot3D[{(3 + 2*x^2), 0, 0}, {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 0.7}, {z, 0,0.7}
, RegionFunction ->Function[{x, y, z},Element[{x, y, z}, Cuboid[{0.4, 0, 0}, {1, 0.4,0.4}]]]]
, Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Cuboid[{0.4, 0, 0}, {1, 0.4, 0.4}]}]}]
```

[image]

to force the `VectorPlot3D` inside the cube!

I don't know why MMA plots vectors outside of the cube. Try the option `VetorPoints->` to avoid this problem.